# Why can't I see the XIB files here in XCode9

Tags: ios, xib, xcode9

The interface to my app is primarily made with XIBs, this is indeed an old project but it ran fine in XCode8. I've finally got to install XCode9 but all my Xib files look like this. Can anyone help explain what's happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: check once editor -> canvas -> show bounds rectangle and show layout rectangle (deselect them)

Comment: Check once editor?

Comment: Check editor menu

Answer (score 1):

i think its a bug of xcode. sometimes its resolve by Quit and restart the xcode. OR clear Derive data from

```
Xcode---> Preferences--->Location--->Derived Data
```

Comment: it cannot be resolved by restarting nor clearing derived data folder. It might be a bug believe

Comment: I've been deleting DerivedData over and over again for a day now, nothing is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Try Editor->Refresh All Views. or try to change View as size to different device 
[image]